# Magento multistore .xml overrides - any way to have a protected global .xml file?

Tags: xml, magento

So, I work for a company with a lot of very, very bad code (cyclomatic complexity on one function I just came across is 64, it's basically 900 lines of if statements).  We run about 30 Magento stores off of one install.  As far as I can tell, there is no single place where I can make a change to an .xml file and have it affect all stores, because page.xml exists in each stores' theme.

So, my question - is there any way to prevent .xml files from being overridden, or to create a new global.xml that will affect all stores, or something?  If those who kludged before me had just used local.xml to override the parts of page.xml they needed to affect, then I wouldn't even be asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a pure design override you need on all stores and themes, but on the same Magento install?  I guess you could add a small module like this:

Create the folder structure `MyModules/LayoutOverrides/etc` inside the folder `magento/app/code/local`.

Inside that folder `magento/app/code/local/MyModules/LayoutOverrides/etc` create the file `config.xml`.

For the `config.xml` file, paste this content and save:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModules_LayoutOverrides>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyModules_LayoutOverrides>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <layoutoverrides>
                    <file>mymodules_layoutoverrides.xml</file>
                </layoutoverrides>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

You also need to create the file `MyModules_LayoutOverrides.xml` inside the folder `magento/app/etc/modules` with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModules_LayoutOverrides>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page/>  <!-- dependency for override to come after Mage_Page -->
            </depends>
        </MyModules_LayoutOverrides>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And then create the design override XML here: `app/design/frontend/base/layout/mymodules_layoutoverrides.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        ...any override you would have for page.xml here
    </default>
</layout>
```

This is all as untested as it gets, but with the right dependecy, so you know the module gets loaded after the stuff you need to override, I see no reason why it shouldn't work.
And as a module, you'll know that it runs - no matter what theme or shop is activated. As I said, untested - but I'm pretty sure it will default back to the `base` folder for the design XML if not found inside the active theme folder.

Comment: 'Build a module' is the same conclusion another developer and I came to a few minutes after I posted this question lol.  Thanks so much for the answer though, I guarantee that dependency would have caused much head-scratching.

Comment: No problem, nice to hear it wasn't a complete waste! :P